# (Minecraft) MoveHelper for custom entity not updating

Tags: java, minecraft-modding

I'm trying to create a shark mob for minecraft 1.8 (using Forge 1.8). Since it's a water mob, the movement functions need to be edited to allow it to path correctly in water.

However, after meticulously copying over the MoveHelper override method from the Guardian entity class, I've noticed something very frustrating - the "this.update" check inside the MoveHelper class is never updated. It should be updating, since I've added a Wander AI to my mob, but it just doesn't. As a consequence, my mob never moves at all.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I just can't see it. If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it.

Here's the code for the EntityGreatWhiteShark class:

```
public class EntityGreatWhiteShark extends EntityWWFish implements IMCAnimatedEntity {

    protected AnimationHandler animHandler = new AnimationHandlerGreatWhiteShark(this);

    public EntityGreatWhiteShark(World par1World) 
    {
        super(par1World);        
        this.moveHelper = new EntityGreatWhiteShark.FishMoveHelper();
        this.tasks.addTask(0, new EntityAIWander(this, 1.0D, 80));        
    }

    protected void applyEntityAttributes()
    {
        super.applyEntityAttributes();
        this.getEntityAttribute(SharedMonsterAttributes.maxHealth).setBaseValue(30.0D);        this.getEntityAttribute(SharedMonsterAttributes.movementSpeed).setBaseValue(0.22D);
        this.getEntityAttribute(SharedMonsterAttributes.followRange).setBaseValue(35.0D);
        this.getAttributeMap().registerAttribute(SharedMonsterAttributes.attackDamage);
        this.getEntityAttribute(SharedMonsterAttributes.attackDamage).setBaseValue(3.0D);
    }

    @Override
    protected void playStepSound(BlockPos p_180429_1_, Block p_180429_2_)
    {
        return;
    }

    protected boolean canTriggerWalking()
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected PathNavigate func_175447_b(World worldIn)
    {
        return new PathNavigateSwimmer(this, worldIn);
    }

    @Override
    protected void entityInit() {
        super.entityInit();
    }

    @Override
    public AnimationHandler getAnimationHandler() {
        return animHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate()
    {
        super.onUpdate();
    }

    public void onLivingUpdate()
    {
        if(!this.getAnimationHandler().isAnimationActive("Swim")) {
            System.out.println("Start swimming");
            this.getAnimationHandler().activateAnimation("Swim", 0);
        }              
        super.onLivingUpdate();        
    }

    @Override
    public void readEntityFromNBT(NBTTagCompound nbttagcompound) {
        super.readEntityFromNBT(nbttagcompound);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeEntityToNBT(NBTTagCompound nbttagcompound) {
        super.writeEntityToNBT(nbttagcompound);
    }

    public float getEyeHeight()
    {
        return this.height;
    }

    @Override
    public EntityAgeable createChild(EntityAgeable ageable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public class FishMoveHelper extends EntityMoveHelper
    {

        private EntityGreatWhiteShark entity = EntityGreatWhiteShark.this;

        public FishMoveHelper()
        {
            super(EntityGreatWhiteShark.this);
        }

        public void onUpdateMoveHelper()
        {
            System.out.println("Updating moverhelper...");

            if (this.update)
            {
                double dirX = this.posX - this.entity.posX;
                double dirY = this.posY - this.entity.posY;
                double dirZ = this.posZ - this.entity.posZ;
                double destDistance = dirX * dirX + dirY * dirY + dirZ * dirZ;
                destDistance = (double)MathHelper.sqrt_double(destDistance);
                dirY /= destDistance;
                float f = (float)(Math.atan2(dirZ, dirX) * 180.0D / Math.PI) - 90.0F;
                this.entity.rotationYaw = this.limitAngle(this.entity.rotationYaw, f, 30.0F);
                this.entity.renderYawOffset = this.entity.rotationYaw;
                float f1 = (float)(this.speed * this.entity.getEntityAttribute(SharedMonsterAttributes.movementSpeed).getAttributeValue());
                this.entity.setAIMoveSpeed(this.entity.getAIMoveSpeed() + (f1 - this.entity.getAIMoveSpeed()) * 0.125F);
                double d4 = Math.sin((double)(this.entity.ticksExisted + this.entity.getEntityId()) * 0.5D) * 0.05D;
                double d5 = Math.cos((double)(this.entity.rotationYaw * (float)Math.PI / 180.0F));
                double d6 = Math.sin((double)(this.entity.rotationYaw * (float)Math.PI / 180.0F));
                this.entity.motionX += d4 * d5;
                this.entity.motionZ += d4 * d6;
                d4 = Math.sin((double)(this.entity.ticksExisted + this.entity.getEntityId()) * 0.75D) * 0.05D;
                this.entity.motionY += d4 * (d6 + d5) * 0.25D;
                this.entity.motionY += (double)this.entity.getAIMoveSpeed() * dirY * 0.1D;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Something is wrong...");
                this.entity.setAIMoveSpeed(0.0F);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the base class, EntityWWFish:

```
public abstract class EntityWWFish extends EntityAnimal{

    private Block waterBlock;
    private boolean isInWater;

    public EntityWWFish(World worldIn) 
    {
        super(worldIn);                
    }

    public void onLivingUpdate()
    {
        super.onLivingUpdate();
    }

    public boolean canBreatheUnderwater()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean CheckInWater() {
        return this.isInWater;
    }

    /**
     * Override this in entity classes for fish that need deeper water to spawn
     */
    @Override
    public boolean getCanSpawnHere()
    {
        int i = MathHelper.floor_double(this.posX);
        int j = MathHelper.floor_double(this.getEntityBoundingBox().minY);
        int k = MathHelper.floor_double(this.posZ);
        BlockPos blockpos = new BlockPos(i, j, k);
        return this.worldObj.getBlockState(blockpos.down()).getBlock() == this.waterBlock && super.getCanSpawnHere();
    }

    /**
     * Whether or not the current entity is in lava
     */
    public boolean handleLavaMovement()
    {
        return this.worldObj.checkNoEntityCollision(this.getEntityBoundingBox(), this);
    }

    /**
     * Get number of ticks, at least during which the living entity will be silent.
     */
    public int getTalkInterval()
    {
        return 120;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if an entity can be despawned, used on idle far away entities
     */
    protected boolean canDespawn()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the experience points the entity currently has.
     */
    protected int getExperiencePoints(EntityPlayer player)
    {
        return 1 + this.worldObj.rand.nextInt(3);
    }

    /**
     * Gets called every tick from main Entity class
     */
    public void onEntityUpdate()
    {
        int i = this.getAir();
        super.onEntityUpdate();

        if (this.isEntityAlive() && !this.isInWater())
        {
            --i;
            this.setAir(i);

            if (this.getAir() == -20)
            {
                this.setAir(0);
                this.attackEntityFrom(DamageSource.drown, 2.0F);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.setAir(300);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPushedByWater()
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```